# Add new tag in XML file with different attributes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I'm trying to add a new line of tag "" with different attributes. I'm able to edit an existing line but not able to add new tag having different attributes.

The XML file

```
   <elementDefinitionPackage elementDefinitionPackageName="kohler-decisionmaker" elementDefinitionPackageVersion="3.2.0.42" elementLibraryFilename="libkohler-decisionmaker.so" elementLibraryVersion="3.2.0.42" minSupportedGDDVersion="1.0" minSupportedUMGFirmwareVersion="1.1.0.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/template" xmlns:cm="http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/common" xmlns:r="http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/rules" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/template XSD_ddt.xsd         http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/rules XSD_rules.xsd         http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/common XSD_common.xsd">
<elementDefinitionModel manufacturerInSymbol="KOHLER" minSupportedVersionInSymbol="1.4" modelInSymbol="DEC4000" modelQualifierInSymbol="DEC4000" symbolTag="KOHLERDEC4000DEC4000">
    <supportedprotocols>
        <supportedProtocol isSubscribable="false" protocolName="MODBUS/RS-485">
            <properties>
                <property category="EXTCOMM" defaultValue="502" definition="PORT" valueType="Integer" />
                <property category="EXTCOMM" defaultValue="60" definition="TIMEOUT" valueType="Integer" />
                <property category="EXTCOMM" defaultValue="1" definition="SLAVEID" valueType="Integer"/>
            </properties>
            <datapoints>
                <datapoint division="COLL_COMP_CEP" nature="PARAMETRIC" programmaticName="t_val_calc_enrg_interval"/>
            </datapoints>
            <events>
                <event address="3.{SLAVEID}.40259.1" programmaticName="t_evt_gen_mainTankAlarm" values="a:1 i:0" />
            </events>
            <commands>
                <command access="RW" address="#RWDA 3.{SLAVEID}.61105 6.{SLAVEID}.61105" division="CONTROL" nature="ENUM" programmaticName="t_st_gen_setControl" valueTypeInDevice="DATA_POINT_VALUE_TYPE_INTEGER" />
            </commands>
        </supportedProtocol>
    </supportedprotocols>
    <rules>
    </rules>
        <similarModels>
            <similarModel manufacturerInSymbol="KOHLER" minSupportedVersionInSymbol="1.4" modelInSymbol="KD440" modelQualifierInSymbol="KD440" symbolTag="KOHLERKD440KD440"/>
        </similarModels>
</elementDefinitionModel>
```

Expected Output XML file

```
      <elementDefinitionPackage elementDefinitionPackageName="kohler-decisionmaker" elementDefinitionPackageVersion="3.2.0.42" elementLibraryFilename="libkohler-decisionmaker.so" elementLibraryVersion="3.2.0.42" minSupportedGDDVersion="1.0" minSupportedUMGFirmwareVersion="1.1.0.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/template" xmlns:cm="http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/common" xmlns:r="http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/rules" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/template XSD_ddt.xsd         http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/rules XSD_rules.xsd         http://xmlns.commonplatform.avocent.com/mss/ddt/common XSD_common.xsd">
<elementDefinitionModel manufacturerInSymbol="KOHLER" minSupportedVersionInSymbol="1.4" modelInSymbol="DEC4000" modelQualifierInSymbol="DEC4000" symbolTag="KOHLERDEC4000DEC4000">
    <supportedprotocols>
        <supportedProtocol isSubscribable="false" protocolName="MODBUS/RS-485">
            <properties>
                <property category="EXTCOMM" defaultValue="502" definition="PORT" valueType="Integer" />
                <property category="EXTCOMM" defaultValue="60" definition="TIMEOUT" valueType="Integer" />
                <property category="EXTCOMM" defaultValue="1" definition="SLAVEID" valueType="Integer"/>
            </properties>
            <datapoints>
                <datapoint division="COLL_COMP_CEP" nature="PARAMETRIC" programmaticName="t_val_calc_enrg_interval"/>
            </datapoints>
            <events>
                <event address="3.{SLAVEID}.40259.1" programmaticName="t_evt_gen_mainTankAlarm" values="a:1 i:0" />
            </events>
            <commands>
                <command access="RW" address="#RWDA 3.{SLAVEID}.61105 6.{SLAVEID}.61105" division="CONTROL" nature="ENUM" programmaticName="t_st_gen_setControl" valueTypeInDevice="DATA_POINT_VALUE_TYPE_INTEGER" />
            </commands>
        </supportedProtocol>
    </supportedprotocols>
    <rules>
    </rules>
        <similarModels>
            <similarModel manufacturerInSymbol="KOHLER" minSupportedVersionInSymbol="1.4" modelInSymbol="KD440" modelQualifierInSymbol="KD440" symbolTag="KOHLERKD440KD440"/>
            <similarModel manufacturerInSymbol="KOHLER" minSupportedVersionInSymbol="1.4" modelInSymbol="A" modelQualifierInSymbol="B" symbolTag="C"/>
        </similarModels>
</elementDefinitionModel>
```

Java Code

```
    private static void updat() {
    NodeList similarmodels = doc.getElementsByTagName("similarModels");
    Element model = null;
    for(int i=0; i<similarmodels.getLength();i++){
        model = (Element) similarmodels.item(i);
        String model = model.getElementsByTagName("similarModel").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        if(model.equalsIgnoreCase("KD440")){
            model.setAttribute("A");
        }else{
            model.setAttribute("B");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way of doing this in JAXB & xsd??

Comment: Can you share the unexpected output, or the code you are using to add the new line. The code you have shared is to edit an existing line, but your question says your code doesn't work when you try to add a new line

Answer (score 0):

Should be no problem, neither with DOM nor with JAXB. In JAXB you should simply be able to create a new `SimilarModel` object which you then can add in the `SimilarModels` object's list.